# Retrieve record type label's translated value

Tags: deployment, package.xml

I have translated record type label name in translation workbench but not able to retrieve it in package xml. record type is not coming in below xml:

*
    CustomObjectTranslation

How can I retrieve record type label translated values in package xml?

Comment: Include object name in your package.xml.  <types>
        <members>Account-ko</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>

Comment: Thanks.. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Include object name in package.xml file along with CustomObjectTranslation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types> 
    <members>Account-ko</members> 
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name> 
    </types> 
    <types> 
    <members>Account</members> 
    <name>CustomObject</name> 
    </types>
    <version>49</version>
</Package>
```

Thanks,